# In a JMS MDB with CMT, is there any way to specify an action to be performed after onMessage has returned and the transaction committed?

Tags: transactions, glassfish, jms, message-driven-bean

I have an MDB which, in response to an incoming message, needs to perform a sequence of actions atomically, for which we're using CMT.  After the message has been processed and the transaction committed, I need to perform one last action - creating and queueing a task for execution in a thread pool, from which entities I'm creating and updating in this MDB will be referenced.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get JMS to invoke a method (like a callback) upon successful (post-commit) return from onMessage().  This callback would have to be executed in the same place as onMessage().

Additional info is that we're using Glassfish 3.1 and the included JMS provider.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Here is some pseudo code to hopefully clarify:

```
public void onMessage(final Message inMessage) {
    addDatabaseRecord();
    addOtherDatabaseRecord();
    updateDatabaseRecord();
}

@RunAfterOnMessageCommits  // Hypothetical annotation
public void postCommit()
    // Must not happen until transaction commits.
    addToThreadPoolWorkQueue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to follow because it does not detail where you want the callback method to be invoked: on the server or on the client.  onMessage() is obviously handled by the client once it receives a message.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've updated to reflect that I want the callback to be invoked from the same place as onMessage() - IE the client.  I was actually envisioning a method right within the same MDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you're. Running in a transaction, you can send the secondary message in the **onMessage** block. If ths transaction rolls back, it will not be sent ( or technically, it will not be received).

Comment: That's what I thought, however I'm looking to replace the output JMS queue with a thread pool operating on a simple BlockingQueue.  I've updated the pseudo code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are running on plain java ee. You could do some tricks with aspect oriented frameworks such as spring-aop to execute specific code before or after a method. It will be a bit xml config - it might be too intrusive in your application architecture though. Spring AOP is, however, non-intrusive on actual code.